# SwiftUI NavigationView not see Image

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationlink

I have a code and make NavigationLink Button, I write Text and Image, But my Image not a see. Pls help me.

```
VStack{
        Image("Coachs")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 370, height: 200)
            //.clipped()
            .cornerRadius(20.0)
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail view here")){
            ZStack{
                Text("Press on me")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                Image("Coachs")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 370, height: 200)
                    //.clipped()
                    .cornerRadius(20.0)

            }


        }}
```

I make screen if you can't understand
 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like SwiftUI bug of handling raster images. Please find below approach for workaround. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

This is an example of cell to be used for your goal. Of course in real case the image name and navigation link destination, etc., can be injected via constructor parameters for reuse purpose.

```swift
struct TestImageCell: View {
    @State private var isActive = false

    var body: some View {
        Image("large_image")    // raster !! image
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 370, height: 200)
            .cornerRadius(20.0)
            .overlay(
                Text("Press on me")              // text is over
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            )
            .onTapGesture { self.isActive.toggle() } // activate link on image tap
            .background(NavigationLink(destination:  // link in background
                Text("Detail view here"), isActive: $isActive) { EmptyView() })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ok, I looked at other image types, try this, it should work:

```
    Image("IMG_4944")
        .renderingMode(.original)  // <----- this
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(width: 370, height: 200)
        .clipped()
        .cornerRadius(20.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I made this test from your code, and all works well, ios 13.4 and catalyst, xcode 11.4 and macos catalina 10.15.4

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "person.2.fill")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 370, height: 200)
                //.clipped()
                .cornerRadius(20.0)

            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail view here")){
                ZStack{
                    Image(systemName: "person.2.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 370, height: 200)
                        //.clipped()
                        .cornerRadius(20.0)
                    Text("Press on me")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }
            }
        }
    }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
}
```

Comment: You put in my code Image system name but I need put a code Image, not working Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4, XCODE Version 11.4 (11E146), iOS 13,4

Comment: you are correct, I did not try with other image type, sorry.