# Swiftui images turn black

Tags: image, swiftui, swiftui-list

In swiftui I have got a problem after an update. Images that are in portrait are getting black when clipped into a square with rounded corners.
I'm using a library called URLImage. Here's the code. Any suggestions what cases this problem. The images in landscape are being clipped correct. It has previously worked but after updating the project in Xcode I now have this problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

```
NavigationLink(destination: OpskriftDetail(opskrift: opskrift)) {
    HStack {
        URLImage(URL(string: opskrift.url)!,
            delay: 0.25,
            processors: [ Resize(size: CGSize(width: 110.0, height: 110.0), scale: UIScreen.main.scale) ],
            content:  {
                $0.image
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                    .clipped()
            }
        )
        .frame(width: 110.0, height: 110.0)
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI NavigationView not see Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168015/swiftui-navigationview-not-see-image)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I removed the processors line and moved the .frame inside content.

```
                    NavigationLink(destination: OpskriftDetail(opskrift: opskrift)) {
                    HStack {
                        URLImage(URL(string: opskrift.url)!,
                                 delay: 0.25,
                                 content:  {
                                    $0.image
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                        .frame(width: 110.0, height: 110.0)
                                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                                        .clipped()
                        })
```

/Bo

PS. I don't know how to remove indentation, sorry :-)